# How to remove border outside of border in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

There is a weird grey border on the outside of my `<Image />` border. Here is an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/01lqk4ijc3k9j7m/Screenshot%202017-12-01%2015.25.11.png?dl=0 (You can see the profile image which has a white border around it and that white border seems to have a grey one)

Here is the code for one of the circles shown in the above dropbox link.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={...}>
  <Image
    style={styles.avatar}
    source={...}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is the `avatar` style:

```
borderColor: '#fff',
borderWidth: 2,
width: 46,
height: 46,
borderRadius: 23,
```

How can I get rid of this weird border?

Comment: Are you referring to the square grey border or the borders around the avatars. You may need to style the TouchOpacity along with the Images

Comment: I'm referring to the grey border, which appears around the white border. 

I tried setting the border color to white on the TouchableOpacity, but it didn't do anything @SteveB

Comment: Can you post the styles for the TouchOpacity. I see a borderWidth  of 1px in Chrome when looking at the box. Removing it, hides part of the grey border.

Comment: I don't have any styles on the TouchableOpacity. I was just saying that adding a border (colour white) does not remove the grey border.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the grey box, not a grey circle around the avatars. I'm not sure if it was dropbox, or your code, but there was a grey box with borderwidth=1 creating a box around the avatars when I looked at your link

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about the grey circles around the avatars. The grey box is from dropbox. @SteveB

Comment: can you share little more code so that scenario can be reproduced at our end ?

Comment: could you insert the https://snack.expo.io of your code

Comment: set touchable opacity backgroundColor to white that will do the trick

Comment: @ParasWatts That didn't seem to fix it. I think there is an issue with RN (when using a border radius on an image and adding a border) as I've seen others with the same problem

Comment: I have used your code and tried running at my end, adding background color is solving the problem on my end. Otherwise i can see little grey line around border of image. Touchable opacity has a little grey color by default , you can try changing color of touchable opacity

Comment: render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{borderRadius:73,backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>                               
        <Image
          style={styles.avatar}
          source={{uri:'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-88mo1ih21k4/Wh-andUF4cI/AAAAAAAAAUA/rKvuxm6IVgs48ap6cHe5iiol6nMyOJW6wCK8BGAs/s250/2017-11-29.jpg'}}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  avatar:{       
    width: 146,
    height: 146,
    borderRadius: 73,               
  },
});

Comment: This is the code which i tried

Answer (score 2):

add `elevation:0` to your avatar style